# Does Unity work well with the ATI Radeon X1200 series?

Tags: 11.04, unity, ati

Does unity works well with ATI Radeon X1200 series?

I faced problem with 10:10 netbook edition unity interface was not showing up icons in the tray,whereas desktop version of 10.10 works absolutely fine.

Let me know if can upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It's working great on mine (ATI Radeon X1200 on my Toshiba Satellite A215-S7437), even better than Unity 2D, actually.
Hope that helps!

Also, Unity doesn't use a system tray as such (although it can be added), it uses indicators. Not all applications have indicators, maybe that's why your icons weren't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure, you can try using a flash drive or live CD to test and see if Unity runs fine for you. It should, since many of the problems in 10.10's version of Unity came from OpenGL problems with mutter.